# Can a Mac be controlled using an API?

Tags: automation, http

I'm developing a plugin for [Hubot](http://hubot.github.com) (a scriptable chatbot) to take a URL, and display it on a Mac Mini connected to a TV in my office.

However I'm not actually sure how feasible this is. Hubot is able to send messages to APIs using HTTP. Is there a known method of allowing a Mac to listen for requests over HTTP, and then run a command (an applescript or shell script perhaps)?

Answer (score 2):

Python is shipped with Macs, you can just use [SimpleHTTPServer](http://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html) to respond to HTTP requests.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you want to do (and what Hubot can do, which I'm not familiar with) – but it seems it is possible through a combination of iChat/Messages and AppleScript to control a Mac through sending commands to a chat account which are then handled by a special script.

The original script that's provided by Apple can be found [here](https://github.com/FreekKalter/apple_scripts/blob/master/iChat/iTunes%20Remote%20Control.applescript) (it should be preinstalled on any recent Mac), and a how-to for setting it up is [here](http://www.maketecheasier.com/mac-osx-remote-control-your-itunes-via-ichat/). I guess that would be a rather … convoluted solution ;)

Of course, you can also enable "Remote Login" in the Sharing Panel in the System Preferences and then connect to the Mac through SSH – which gives you control over the Mac via the CLI.

Answer (score 1):

If you activate PHP on your mini and restart Apache, then you can send commands to the web server through http GET and POST commands. Although POST is more secure and the recommended method. I use this method to send commands from an Arduino to a mac and have it store data in a database. If you want to experiment without changing the Apache setup on your Mac then try MAMP, it is free and open source.

PHP is the backend of the internet and can do just about anything you need, (or you can run javascript) to update a web page that will display whatever you want on your TV.

Comment: An additional thought is to investigate Apple Remote Events like here: http://support.apple.com/kb/PH10710